# Nothing inserted in Access database table even without no query errors (c#)

Tags: c#

I am not able to see data inserted into an Access database file. My query is fine with no errors but nothing is seen in the database table. Some people are saying that you have to enable "Copy always" property in order to copy the file to output directory but I cannot find that property.

Comment: Are you asking where you can enable "Copy always" on a file in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes sir.Because I cannot see Access db file in solution explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solution Explorer right click on your Access db and select properties.inside the properties windows there is "Copy To Output Directory" you can set it to "copy always"

Comment: But Access db file is not appearing there.My all forms and resources are present in solution explorer but not db file.

Comment: @SyedHassaanAli, ok right click on your project in solution explorer and choose add>existing item.. and add the file to your project

Comment: Thank you sir you solved that problem.But I have one more question.My question is why the data table is empty even when the insertion process is successful(query is executed with no errors).

Comment: @SyedHassaanAli You're welcome, I suggest you mark this answer as correct and then ask your other question in a new post and post the part of the code that's not working, so people can view and answer accordingly

Comment: Here you go sir. Now can you please help me in solving my other problem of empty table asked above.

Comment: @SyedHassaanAli,Thank you,but please post your code because without it me or anybody can't help you